Google SSO is capitalizing my email address, I want lowercase
Let's get this out of the way: I know email addresses are case-insensitive, but my personal preference is lowercased.
Over the past year or two, I've noticed that Google has been capitalizing my email address in SSO flows. Allow me to dox myself. All the way back in Gmail beta, I signed up with "crunk1". My Google account settings still show "crunk1@...". I cannot find any settings anywhere that have "Crunk1". However, if you look at the following screenshots from my phone camera, you'll see "Crunk1" in Google's SSO (OIDC it seems) flow:


I know that there is almost no functional difference between "crunk1" and "Crunk1"...except when third parties do JIT user provisioning and autocreate an account with "Crunk1", sometimes immutably.
I don't know where else Google uses the capitalized version of my email, but I would like it lowercase everywhere. I've contacted support a few times, but so far, it has always ended with side-stepping my request/question, "Good news! Email addresses are case-insensitive."
Anyone know if I can modify this?

There Is nothing that end-users can do other than trying to contact Google support again. Go to https://support.google.com/mail and check the options that Google offers to you
